# How can we run jest unit tests along with npm start or npm build?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

Each time we try to run Jest unit tests we have to run npm test. Is there any way with which I can run these tests when I'm building my application (at time of npm start or npm build)

Comment: just use another terminal :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple steps in package.json like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "sh start.sh",
    "test": "sh test.sh",
    "test_start": "npm test && npm start"
  }
```

while running your test, simply run

```
npm run test_start
```

This will ensure that your test is successful before it runs start.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add the `npm test` step in your `start` command in your package.json, like this for example:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm run test && node server.js"
  "test": "jest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have these in my package.json and its really useful to have jest coverage will give you a detailed report on whether any of your files are missing tests.

```
"test": "jest --testPathPattern='/App/*'",
"test:coverage": "jest --coverage && open coverage/lcov-report/index.html || xdg-open coverage/lcov-report/index.html",
"test:updateSnapshot": "jest --updateSnapshot"
```